# Safe voltage from Line to Ground 220V AC single phase?

Tags: wiring, grounding, voltage

[[ CORRECTION: L-N should be N-G or N-E. My mistake. ]]

I live on the ground floor of an apartment building in India. Standard Indian wall voltage is 220V AC. I'm about 5 meters from the circuit breaker box (CBB) down the hall. This CBB only handles the ground floor. Next to the CBB is another electrical box that (I think) is a distribution panel (I'm not an electrician so I'm not sure). If needed I can take pics of the boxes and post them.

When I plug my grounded socket tester in to my grounded wall receptacle, I get about 4.3V Line-Neutral. (My socket tester has a nice LED screen showing all the details.) The socket tester says the connections are correct.

I have an old heavy VGuard 500VA voltage stabilizer (VS) with a ground pin. So I plug the VS into the wall and my socket tester into the VS. At the VS output the socket tester reads about 6V Line-Neutral.

Do these L-N voltages seem safe? Or are the L-N voltages high?

What other details you need?

Comment: Pictures of everything involved will definitely help.

Comment: Maybe some details about the socket tester.  A plain voltage meter/tester will read full voltage between L-N and L-G(220v) if things are right.  Your tester might be reading leakage or something.

Comment: You should be seeing L-N  (and L-G) voltages more like 220-230V. Is the outlet controlled by a switch that’s off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're reading that right?  You should be getting about 220V Line to Neutral, about 220V Line to Ground, and something close to 0V Neutral to Ground.

I could believe 4.3V Neutral to Ground.  It's not ideal, but not actually dangerous.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful and gives me good context.